# static_assert and Intel C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-assert, icc

Reading [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

> A static assert declaration may appear at block scope (as a block
>   declaration) and **inside a class body** (as a member declaration)

OK, now I have the following code:

```
struct foo_t
{
    static constexpr std::size_t maxAlignment()
    {
        // This is just a sample; I removed real code from this method.
        return std::max(alignof(__m128), __alignof(__m256));
    }

    static_assert(0 == ((maxAlignment() -1) & maxAlignment()), "some message");
};
```

Neither MSVC 2015  nor Intel C++ 16.0.2 compile this code (the former shows "error C2131: expression did not evaluate to constant" and the latter shows "function call must have a constant value in a constant expression" error and points to call of `maxAlignment` in `static_assert`).

But MSVC 2015 Update 1 **does** compile the following code, while Intel C++ 16.0.2 **does not**:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Alignment>
struct foo_t
{
    static constexpr std::size_t maxAlignment()
    {
        return std::max(std::alignment_of<T>::value, Alignment);
    }

    static_assert(0 == ((maxAlignment() -1) & maxAlignment()), "some message");
};

foo_t<__m128, 16> foo {};
// foo_t<__m128, 33> boo {};  // here `static_assert` will stop compilation
```

(So, MSVC can handle `static_assert` when it's inside a **template** class body)

But the following code is compiled successfully by both of the compilers (`static_assert` is outside of a class body; it appears at a block scope):

```
struct foo_t
{
    static constexpr std::size_t maxAlignment()
    {
        return std::max(alignof(__m128), __alignof(__m256));
    }
};

static_assert(0 == ((foo_t::maxAlignment() -1) & foo_t::maxAlignment()), "some message");
```

**My question is**: Did I miss something or is that Intel C++ compiler's error?

Comment: _"MSVC 2015 compiles the code from above successfully."_ Not on my computer: _"error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant"_ I got the same result on Intel & GCC.

Comment: @ZDF I have 'Update 1' -- may be this causes MSVC 2015 to compile that code (when `static_assert` is inside the class body).

Comment: Compilers are all over the place on `constexpr` support right now; we've encountered code-generation bugs with them in GCC and MSVC.

Comment: Ruslan, I do not understand. What I meant is that I got the same errors from **all** three compilers. @Crashworks It is hard to believe that all three compilers are wrong in the same way. Maybe it is about some obscure ISO statement .

Comment: @ZDF That's my fault! I too over-simplified the samples.. I'll edit my post to show it... Thanks for point me out on that!

Comment: The reason MSVC2015-U1 compiles your updated code, while others don't, might be [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/02/constexpr-in-vs2015-update-1/): _"...we’ve fixed ~45 bugs related to constexpr usage... There are ~30 bugs remaining on our backlog in this area..."_

Comment: @ZDF And to create a portable code I have to move `static_assert` out of a class body? And wait till all compilers will be fixed?

Comment: It looks like there is no other way. If keeping the assert declaration in struct is a must, you may use the template workaround. Use one argument, with default value and then typedef.

Comment: for most recent intel icc, you can try -std=c++14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall it right constexpr functions can't be used until they are fully defined and class-member constexpr functions are undefined until the class is defined and it means that you can't use constexpr member-function inside the class-scope `static_assert` which defines this very function.

But you can make this function standalone(it is already static anyway) and it will do the job. It should compile everywhere.

Comment: The function is `static`, yes, but it depends on template's arguments.

Comment: @RuslanGaripov, standalone functions might have template arguments as well

Comment: But the fact that ICC can't compile a template class -- what about this? Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: @RuslanGaripov, I'd say yes — it is a bug since all other compilers compile it. But to be sure I'd consult with the Standard

Comment: It is a bug: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/610395